# Как правильно дэплоить приложение Angular + Laravel?

Tags: laravel, angular, развертывание, deploy

Я написал приложение на Angular с использованием Laravel в качестве апихи. Как теперь правильно задэплоить приложение. Надо ли пихать файлы сборки ангуляра из /dist в папку public?

Answer (score 0):

В общем, потратив n-е количество часов я всё-таки разобрался. Не знаю, правильно ли я сделал или нет, но у меня всё работает.

За основу можете взять вот [эту статью](https://medium.com/eliteng/integrate-and-deploy-laravel-5-and-angular-5-project-to-a-shared-hosting-8ce44050df91#_=_) (внимание, английский язык)

Кроме всего, что написано в статье, я добавил ещё один `.htaccess` в папку  `public` бэкэнда со следующим содержанием:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

без этой штуки у меня на все мои запросы с фронта приходит 404 - Объект не найден c бэкэнда. Ну а всё остальное - как описано в статье выше.

Ещё я поменял стратегию ссылок на фронте и установил провайдер для `LocationStratagy` - `HashLocationStratagy` в корневом модуле фронта

```
{ provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }
```

Ну и собственно всё. Всё должно работать